# How add new empty-lines in the message of one-line command "git commit -m"

Tags: git, commit, git-commit, commit-message

If I want to not use any text editor and put all the commit message including subject and body lines into the useful one-line command:

`$ git commit -m 'message including subject and body lines'`

, I need to insert first body-line two lines after subject and the next lines just at the next new line.

For example:

feat: Derezz the master control program

- MCP turned out to be evil and had become intent on world domination.
- This commit throws Tron's disc into MCP.

So I tried to use "\n" but didn't solve the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're working in Bash (on Linux or in Git Bash on Windows), then you can use the `$'...'` syntax from Bash, which lets you use `\n` and other escape sequences:

`$ git commit -m $'message subject\n\nmessage body'`

will create a commit with message

```
message subject

message body
```

Comment: Excellent! that is the solution i was looking for. thanks so much!

Answer (score 4):

Method 1:

```
git commit -m "title" -m "A paragraph." -m "Another paragraph."
```

Method 2:

```
git commit -m "title

A paragraph.

Another paragraph."
```

They have exactly the same outcome. Note that in the 2nd method you need to punch <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice at the end of each line (except the last one).

Comment: Excellent dude! Your method 2, is another possible solution i was looking for. thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-m` multiple times:

```
git commit -m 'message including subject' -m 'and body lines'
```

Every `-m text` separated with an empty line so this command will produce

```
message including subject

and body lines
```

Comment: thank you dude. i knew it but the problem about your solution is that it places new empty lines between body-lines too. and  that's not pleasant by me.